# Check either the dynamically appended content already exist or not using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu using bootstrap. In which i'm having a 3 list items containing 5 child items in each of them.

These 3 list items is used to append dynamic content in 3 different `divs(div#Accounts1, div#Accounts2, div#Accounts3)` in the body respectively.

[image]

**What I want to achieve is:**

I want to add the append the content dynamically by on click on child list items of these 3 parent list items.

But before I append dynamic content, I want to check that the content doesn't already exist. For that purpose I am using the class name as selector.

**What I have achieved is:**

Dynamic content is appending and that's not the issue.

The only thing remains is to check either the respective div already exist or not in specific div.

The selector that I'm using in if statement is not perfect as it is only allows me to generate a div only once for any specific `Accounts`.

**How I can manage to select/search if the dynamic content already exist or not for each div in the body?**

```js
$(function() {

  $('li#Configure > ul.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'li', function(event) {


    var divSelector = "I managed the selector it is working fine";
    
    if ($('div.li' + ($(this).index() + 1)).size() === 1) return;

    $(divSelector).append(
      '<div class="li' + ($(this).index() + 1) + '"' +
      '<h4 class="ui-widget-header">' + $(this).text() + '</h4>' +
      '</div>'
    );


  });
});
```

```css
/****  Sub DropDown Menus ****/

.dropdown-submenu
{
    position: relative;
}

    .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu
    {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -6px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu > a:after
    {
        display: block;
        content: " ";
        float: right;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
        border-left-color: #ccc;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: -10px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after
    {
        border-left-color: #fff;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left
    {
        float: none;
    }

        .dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu
        {
            left: -100%;
            margin-left: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
            border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BrandLogo</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home Page <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li id="Configure" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Configure<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">Accounts1</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Option1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option5</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">Accounts2</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Option1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option5</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#">Accounts3</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Option1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option5</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: I would just assume it doesn't and overwrite - that way you win either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking if a text exists in a selector, using JQuery you can do:

```
if( parseInt($("div:contains(your_text)").size()) > 0 )
```

Comment: The content is dynamic added and it is changing from time to time. As content changes so can't use a hard coded selector. That's why I used classes but it is working for only one.

Comment: Understood. But you might also have the dynamically generated texts in some sort of collection (arrays?). With the array of already displayed text, you can then do an `indexOf()` to see if the **to-be-displayed** text is already present.